# How does the mysqldump lock the partition table in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, partitioning, mysqldump

Does the below query needs `--single-transaction` when `date='2022-12-03'` represent the values of one partition. There is no `DML` (except SELECT) process on this partition but exists on other partitions. (In other words, MySQL lock all partition or specific ones when `--single-transaction` does not use)

```
mysqldump -u User -p'pass' $DB $TABLE --where="date='2022-12-03'" > db.sql
```

Comment: Read about partition pruning.

Comment: @Akina thanks, I read about [partition pruning](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/partitioning-pruning.html#:~:text=This%20%E2%80%9Ccutting%20away%E2%80%9D%20of%20unneeded,same%20column%20definitions%20and%20data.) before, and I know how partition works. But I did not find anything related my question or at least it is unclear to me. More detail will be helpful.

Comment: While building the execution plan the server decides does the partition pruning can be applied. If so then server defines what partitions should be used. And on the execution step server should lock (if needed) only those partitions which are needed in the query execution. Because on the execution step the server only performs the job provided from previous step, it does not know what is the source of this job.

Comment: This means there is no need for `--single-transaction` because in my case there is no operation on this partition, all rows belong to the same partition, Am I right?